# C# str.Replace only replaces first character

Tags: c#, string, replace, character

This is my code, I know it isn't optimal, but it works for me.

```
 private void textBox_title1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string title1 = textBox_title1.Text;
        string currentDirectory = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
        DateTime folderDate = DateTime.Today;
        string workingFolder = folderDate.ToString("ddMMMyy");
        string mailingDir = ("mailingdir\\");
        string indexPage = (mailingDir + "\\" + workingFolder + "\\" + "index.html");
        String appdir = Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath);
        String title1open = Path.Combine(appdir, mailingDir, workingFolder, "index.html");
        string str = File.ReadAllText(title1open, Encoding.UTF8);

        str = str.Replace("[title1]", title1);
        File.WriteAllText(title1open, str);
    }
```

However, this only saves the first character that is entered into `textBox_title1`

Comment: Can you give us an example about what you want and what you are getting?

Comment: On the second change - which could be a char being entered, or some variable-length string being pasted etc - `[title1]` doesn't exist in the file, so can't be replaced (it's been 'written over' with the initial change), and hence the code 'does nothing'.

Comment: @MicrosoftDN I would like to put text into the textbox, and let the code replace [title1] with that text.

Comment: @GrantThomas The first character gets saved correctly, but the remaining text gets lost.

Comment: @IvoHulsman Precisely; my explanation is for _why_ it happens this way.

Comment: @IvoHulsman, please show an example of what's in the textbox, what `str` contains before the replace and what it contains afterwards. At the moment, your explanation of what happens doesn't fit the code, so you need to provide more details.

Comment: @GrantThomas but this is the initial change right? The very first change in the file changes [mailingdate], so that wouldn't affect [title1] right?

Comment: Voting to close as *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.*

Comment: No, on the face of it `[mailingdate]` shouldn't affect it, but let's assume that works by date selection which might update the whole field at once with a valid date/time and _just so happens to work, incidentally_; but for a title I assume a user it typing it char by char, hence the first char for the title replaces `[title1]` with that char, for the characters typed after that, there is no `[title1]` to replace. If the first change to the title text box was a pasting of a complete title/word, you should see that work well, but again, only incidentally.

Comment: My apologies @DavidArno. 'str' contains the outcome of 'folderDate.ToString("ddMMMyy");' prior to changing it again with the input of the textbox. I want the code to replace things in textboxes with certain bits of text in a html file. The first change works well, but is not done via a textbox, it's done via a button. If I enter text into a textbox, only the first character gets saved to the html file.

Comment: @GrantThomas Ah yes now I understand! Thank you for clearing this up. Now I only need to figure out a bit of code that replaces all of the text with the textbox input.

Comment: You could try only updating when the form field loses focus, indicating the user may have moved on from/completed editing that field - that works on assumptions though, so it would have to be clearly intentional and expected by you app - still, once you write out that result, it is final, so you'd have to disable to field or give some other visual feedback. You could always allow all fields to be edited on the form and then write it all to the file in one go when done, as dictated by the user clicking a button, say. Or, read from a template and write to an 'instance' file.